# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( even when line is empty

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have this HTML:

```
<template is="auto-binding" id="container-binding-template">
  <core-scaffold id="scaffold" onscroll={{containerScrolled}}>
    <div id="container">
```

*The auto-binding template and `<core-scaffold>` are part of [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org).*

This is the JavaScript:

```
var template = document.querySelector('#container-binding-template');

template.containerScrolled = function() {
  // regardless of the code here, the error will occur (event if it's empty)
};
```

When I run this code I get the following error (in Chrome DevTools):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (                                           VM*xxxx*:2

When I open the VM*xxxx* file (e.g. VM1362) I see this code:

```
(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {function () {
    // This line contains the same code as in containerScrolled(). This is where the error is pointing to.
  }
};}}}})
```

**What's causing this error? How can I fix it?**
Any help would be appreciated.

### Update #1: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju3ga9xh/2/)

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the code in the VMxxxx file? Because at present I can't see that it is doing anything- it seems to be creating an anonymous function and then not assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @PhilipAdler Yes, that is the entirety of the VM*xxxx* file.

Comment: @Grundy I'm still working on the JSFiddle (I'm having trouble importing the Polymer elements)

Comment: @Grundy I have updated the question with a JSFiddle

Comment: @PhilipAdler I updated the question with JSFiddle. There you can see the VM*xxxx* file.

Comment: try see sample on [polymer-project.org](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html#features) and go to a plunkr from it, i can see that you forget add `http://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js` to your app

Comment: @Grundy I do have webcomponents.js in my app. When I add it to the JSFiddle, the fiddle doesn't work. Nonetheless, the error is the exactly the same in the fiddle without the .js file as in my app that had the .js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event attribute should be `on-scroll`. What you have there is the native inline event handlers, which expect the input to be the body of a function.